# Running app on real device in safe mode?

Tags: android, eclipse

My device is not showing up in eclipse [**Note that this is not a dublicate, read further**].
I have booted my PC into safe mode, and I guess there's no options or I may setting or service enabled for usb adb/debugging.For instance, sound is also disabled in safe mode, but there is a way of getting it on safe mode by adding the service to

`"_hklm\system\currnetcontrolset\control\safeboot\_"`,maybe.

Please tell me which services to put here or a way to detect my device.

---

I'm running *Windows 7 Home Basic*, *Galaxy Fit GTS-5670, 2.3.6*

---

*My device is properly recognized in normal boot, but not in Safe Boot/Mode.*

Comment: Please specify your OS, Device on which you are currently debugging and the Android version of your device from Settings> About Device>Android Version

Comment: Ok then please check your usb drivers under the SDK manager is installed or not along with the Samsung usb debug driver

Comment: yes it is there, as I mentioned my device is correctly recognised in normal boot but not in safe boot.

Answer (score 1):

Basically safe mode is used only for the OS to load when there is a system-critical problem that interferes with the normal operation of Windows( removal of viruses ,worms etc. are done in safe mode).In safe mode your Operating System runs in isolation mode i.e. it will not load all the functions but only some to repair and perform the evaluation of your system.

Due to which most of the device drivers will  not be loaded .So the eclipse will not display you the device as the USB debug device driver is not loaded by the operating system(windows 7 in this case).

Comment: I know this, that's why I'm asking which service to add; my computer not works properly in normal mode and also eclipse runs very smooth in safe mode

Comment: Define "not works normally" is it the slowness of the eclipse or something else and adding any new service would only do is conflict the meaning of Safe mode.At the max you can do in the safe mode is start safe mode with network,Audio drivers and browse or else you need to shift to Linux(Linux is the OS which makes the most of your processor efficiently) if the problem regarding the system is severe.

Comment: Try doing the trouble shoot from the Action centre it might show you some details regarding the issues your might be facing or also solve it.